# ngOnDestroy not working on phone, but works on website

Tags: html, css, iphone, angular

I'm having a problem that I'm noticing on my phone. Note that everything done in developer tools, resizing, throttling; it all works as intended on my desktop. This my problem:

One: When refreshing the website on my phone. My user count that's part of my chat system doesn't refresh. Here is my code in Angular (Typescript) that keeps the user count up to date:

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.chatService.leaveChat('User left');
  }

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  doSomething() {
    this.ngOnDestroy();
  }
```

ngOnDestroy detects when the component is removed. @HostListener detects when the user closes the browser window or refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems something related to browser specific.

beforeUnload Event

[image]

More info in.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @HostListener is for when the user closes out the browser.

Comment: I've edited my answer, seems to be not supported on Safari. According to MDN, and that's can explain why the issue in browser phone. :/